# How long do resolved Promises take to enter the task queue?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, task-queue, event-loop

I'm still trying to figure out the event loop and when exactly things tick/when the task queues are processed.

```
console.log('start');

Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  console.log('promise');
});

console.log('end');
```

This outputs the following:

```
> "start"
> "end"
> "promise"
```

Shouldn't the promise resolve right away and thus the call stack would be empty right after (before "end" is printed) and thus the callback would be processed as a task before "end" is printed?

I'm clearly missing something here about either a) when resolved Promise callbacks are added to the task queue or b) when tasks are processed in the event loop.

Comment: A promise is an asynchronous task, it takes it's time to resolve the result. Depending on what you're requesting, it can take long or it will be solved quickly.

Comment: Even with an “instant resolve” the promise still gets put into its own task and is async. It is hard to predict when that then gets executed and/or will resolve. If you truly need it to resolve before execution of later statements then use async/await.

Comment: @Variable I get that, but it's resolved immediately in this case. Is it because it still needs to offload that request to a worker which takes some time?

Comment: The function called  in `.then` method is a microtask, which will be resolved whenever the browser is idle so even if the Promise is resolved instantaneously , there's still a delay before the execution of the then.

Comment: @Axnyff there is a delay, but it should be executed before the "end" in that case right? Since right after the resolution the task would be in the callback queue and the stack would be empty and so the callback queue would be checked and the event would be there for processing (again, assuming instantaneous resolution.)

Comment: The task queue is periodically looked at by the js process. Even if a task resolved right away, it’s result will only be processed when the queue is next looked at.

Comment: @ChrisCousins my understanding is that occurs whenever the stack clears, is that incorrect? MDN states `The processing of functions continues until the stack is once again empty; then the event loop will process the next message in the queue (if there is one).`

Comment: The current task doesn't magically stop just because something got pushed to another queue; the current task executes until it returns before _anything else_ happens.

Comment: @tkausl I never stated that it stops, just that the stack becomes empty. See comment above why my current understanding shows that this should result in processing of the queue at that point.

Comment: Why would the stack become empty? The `console.log('start');` and the `console.log('end');` are in the same function, which means they are in the same stack frame.

Comment: @tkausl I see, so even if it's not explicitly part of a function per say (for example just code typed into the main scope) it is still considered like a main() function or something similar (to make a `C` analogy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was considering the stack to be clear after the immediately resolved Promise, but in reality the stack is *not* clear at that point. You could think of the entire block of code being executed as like the `main()` function of a `C` program to make a `C` analogy.

Thus, since the stack is not clear, even though an microtask in now in the callback queue waiting to be processed, it doesn't get processed until after all the synchronous JS code in the main thread is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Using the terminology you used. Task queues are executed when only platform code is running - that is when all synchronous code has finished executing. Your code is guaranteed to execute in exactly that order.

They are run *before* the event loop (they're "microtasks") which is why your `then` executes before any `setTimeout` for example.